# How to make RStudio File Navigator open Current Working Directory by default?

Tags: r, rstudio

This is a very small issue but every time I do it, I wonder if there is such a convenience.

In RStudio, file navigator always opens in home directory by default. Is there a way to make it open the current working directory automatically or by using a shortcut?

Answer (score 0):

To open current working directory you can simply use the "Set As Working Directory" button in Files -> More menu.

[image]